# Mysql_fetch_array,assoc,row resorting the array after fetching from db

Tags: php, mysql

I am executing a query as

```
SELECT distinct dr.author as author , count(dr.author) as count FROM e_core_internet_analysis_58 dr,client_competitors,e_master_article_about WHERE `clientId`='173' AND dr.author!='' and client_competitors.clientId='173' and client_competitors.competitorId= e_master_article_about.company_id and e_master_article_about.id=dr.article_about_id and date(dr.publish_time) BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-10' and dr.feed_class in ('Microblogs') and dr.company_name in ('Edelweiss - GIM','Edelweiss - WCM','India Infoline - WCM','Motilal Oswal - WCM','Emkay','KR Choksey','Motilal Oswal','Prabhudas Liladhar') group by author order by count desc limit 0,20
```

When I run this query in the database, I get the result as in the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb0nU.png)

When I fetch the array using the following code

```
$query_stack_st = "SELECT  distinct dr.author as author  , count(dr.author) as  count FROM e_core_internet_analysis_$sector_id dr,client_competitors,e_master_article_about WHERE `clientId`='".$client_id."'  AND dr.author!='' and client_competitors.clientId='".$client_id."' and client_competitors.competitorId= e_master_article_about.company_id and e_master_article_about.id=dr.article_about_id and date(dr.publish_time) BETWEEN '".$from."'   AND  '".$to."' and dr.feed_class in ('".rtrim($genre_id,"','")."') and dr.company_name in ('".rtrim($company_id,"','")."') group by author  order by count desc limit 0,20 ";

$res_stack_st = mysql_query($query_stack_st);
while($row =mysql_fetch_array($res_stack_st)) {
echo $row['author']."<br>";
}
```

I get the result as :

```
CNBC-TV18
Motilal Oswal Group
Save & Grow Money
NewsOnFire
OptionsTip
Sanjeev P Saikia
CNBC-TV18 News
Green Hedge Capital
Ajinkya Ambre
3NovicesChennai
India Market Updates
SanjayChowdary
Fin Thoughts
Investsmart - Sapan
moneycontrol
Shyam Sharma
Indian Stocks Update
Kairavi Shah
Ashutosh Tilak
RANJAN BUDA.
```

which is not expected. After sorting count in descending order, it also sorts group of authors in descending order. For e.g.

```
SanjayChowdary
Fin Thoughts
```

Both have same count but 
Fin Thoughts should be first and then Sanjay Chowdary as in the image.

Both the queries are exactly the same as I echoed it in my browser and executed in the db. I tried different options like `mysql_fetch_assoc,` `mysql_fetch_array`, `mysql_fetch_row`, etc but still got the same results.

Can someone please help me with this issue.

Comment: Can anyone please reply to this answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to change here in your query.add auther column to set order by ascending.

```
   group by author  order by count desc,auther asc limit 0,20 ";
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. In fact it sorted the overall author list and not only the first 20 results